# Expo button inside flatlist always rerendering

Tags: javascript, expo, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist with up to 4 buttons in it (pressable) also there is a while loop which checks things and rerenders. The Problem is when its rerendering it also rerenders the flatlists values and the button wont be select able because of that. because it always will be rerendering. how can i fix this?

Like i want the button to behave as if he wouldnt be inside the flatlist because inside it will not be pressable while the loop is running and rerendering

I tried different solutions already none worked for me

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example